# Best practice Design Pattern for API Automation Framework

Tags: node.js, rest, graphql, web-api-testing, apollo-client

In our project we need to automate APIs written in Node.js, which uses GraphQL and REST, for that we have to develop an API Automation Framework which have to support (Sync, Async calls).

Is there any good practice Design Pattern to setup an API Automation Framework?

Comment: What is API Automation? For testing? For documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Speaking strictly, about design patterns alone: you could use the Builder pattern and backed by the single responsibility principle.

Personally, in our organization we use a **RestAssured**-driven framework with a Builder pattern approach.

As an example of the structure, we have data transfer objects to hold the request and the response of the APIs. Then we have implementation classes specifically for hitting the APIs.

If you plan to use **TestNG** like we do, then you can have a test class with a separate `DataProvider` class, which helps with code separation and easier debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using Cucumber.js plus one of the popular REST client packages.

[Cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) is one of Behavior Driven Development framework that can make the API testing readable and more managable.

The following article compares several packages that can be used to automate RESTful APIs

[5 Ways to Make HTTP Requests in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html)

There are some [samples](https://github.com/cuketest/demos) on API testing as well as Cucumber.js framework.

Also, to create the test script, consider using [CukeTest](http://cuketest.com) authoring together with Postman (which serves good debugging purpose)

Answer (score 1):

For the integration testing of GraphQL API's, I have used [graphql-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tester).

The design will be very specific to your project.

1. If you have your own API server,
   a. Call the API.
   b. You can hit the backend(DB) and check the expected fields are updated in the DB.
   c. Validate the HTTP responses.
2. If you have written a wrapper for 3rd party API's,  understand the response from the third party API's and mock them using mock servers/JSON servers.

For the integration testing(Black box), it does not matter on the REST/GraphQL(everything is HTTP calls).  Try to choose a language where you can get all the clients( DB, HTTP etc.,).

Have a sanity test case like all services should be up and running before you start your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mocha.js](https://mochajs.org/) . According to official site "Mocha is a feature-rich JavaScript test framework running on Node.js and in the browser, making asynchronous testing simple and fun. Mocha tests run serially, allowing for flexible and accurate reporting, while mapping uncaught exceptions to the correct test cases. Hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha)."

**Why you should chose it**: 
Mocha can run on either node.js or in the browser. When compared to other javascript testing frameworks like Jasmine, you can see that Mocha’s handling of asynchronous testing is a key factor for choosing it. When testing API, we need to send some data to an endpoint and use the data that comes back to make a call to another endpoint. For example, we need to get a user, then grab that user’s id to get all locations that belong to that user.

[Chai](http://www.chaijs.com/)
Unlike Jasmine, an additional assertion library must be used to supplement Mocha. Chai is an assertion library that lets you choose the assertion interface that you like best, including “assert”, “expect”, and “should”.

**Why you should chose it**: Although Mocha can be used with any assertion library and Chai can be used with any javascript testing framework, many javascript developers choose to use them together. We can use Chai’s “expect” interface to chain natural language assertions together, so we could test the JSON coming back from our API endpoints thoroughly.

Reference : for more  [see this](http://developmentnow.com/2015/02/05/make-your-node-js-api-bulletproof-how-to-test-with-mocha-chai-and-supertest/)